# When Blender 2.8 release date?

Tags: installation

Currently blender 2.8 beta is available , so when is the release version will do?
also I need a tutorial for that version...

thanks in advance

Comment: Beta version is not enough to you for now? Are you a professional, if you are learning, Beta or 2.79 version should be enough for it. If you only want to know the realese date, so it is not yet declared by the Blender foundation.

Comment: When its Ready™

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's speculating about Blender development.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 12-4-19**
Mid May will be the UI Cleaning. July will be the first temptive date:
https://code.blender.org/2019/04/2-80-release-plan/

---

Today´s Blender episode may have some answers for you:
https://youtu.be/f71Joh_mNnU

Overall, the developers are going to be teamed up like the Avenger's end game, you know...because we don´t move on. Jokes aside, the devs are putting hard effort to finish Blender 2.8 and set up some deep code things for the future. These include:

- Everything Nodes
- New Outliner (hypergraph) - Which basically ordains how data is stored in Blender
- New Asset managment (Like standard 3d applications elsewhere)
- Graphic improvement with Eevee (Higher, Further, Faster, baby).

And it´s most likely that a solid release for Blender 2.8 is on the **horizon of the last quarter of the year** (to say the least). Why? Because around October is the Blender Conference which year after year is the goal to present new Blender improvements.

Vote me up as answer, if you find this URL VIDEO, these summarized points on what Devs are working on and a possible RELEASE DATE, useful. Thanks.

BFCT_Schiller